# How do I cythonize a django project?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, shell, cython, built-in

### Update:

#### Goals:

1. To reduce code size.
2. To reduce latency in the request-response model.
3. To make it execute fast.

#### Original question:

How to convert all .py files to .pyx or .pyc?
I was trying to cythonize my existing project.
As it requires to convert all .py file to .pyc.
I came across an easy solution to do the same.
Just wanted to share this for another seeker like me.

Comment: pyc has nothing to do with Cython

Comment: Also, you can compile .py files with Cython. There's actually no need to rename them as pyx.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

with python installed, you could just do-

```
python -m compileall .
```

or

```
python3 -m compileall .
```

on your program directory.

Comment: I think OP has got confused between pyc (Python bytecode files) and compiled Cython modules thus asked a question that doesn't really make sense. I don't think this is what they're really after.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a [`compileall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html) module exactly for this

```
import compileall

compileall.compile_dir('Lib/', force=True)

# Perform same compilation, excluding files in .svn directories.
import re
compileall.compile_dir('Lib/', rx=re.compile(r'[/\\][.]svn'), force=True)

# pathlib.Path objects can also be used.
import pathlib
compileall.compile_dir(pathlib.Path('Lib/'), force=True)
```

If you just want to compile 1 file you can use [`py_compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html#py_compile.compile)

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("file.py","output/path")
```

Comment: I think OP has got confused between pyc (Python bytecode files) and compiled Cython modules thus asked a question that doesn't really make sense. I don't think this is what they're really after.

Answer (score 0):

The existing solutions on stackoverflow required installation of additional modules.
The below solution uses built-in linux module.

```
find . -depth -name "*.py" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mv -- "$f" "${f%.py}.pyx"' \;
```

This works recursively for all files in the folder.